# React Native set style as State

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, state

I want to use `backgroundColor` of `style1` as a state, and change it in the function `change()`.
How can I access `style1`?

My point is to call the function `change` from another function, making the button change its color to yellow, then change it's colour to blue again after sometime.

```
export default class App extends Component{ 
  constructor (props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      //style1.backgroundColour: blue  //? Can't 
    }
    this.change=this.change.bind(this)
  }

  change() {
    this.setState({ style1.backgroundColour: yellow }) //?
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <View style={styles.style1} > </View>

    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  style1:{
    padding: 5,
    height: 80,
    width: 80,  
    borderRadius:160,    
    backgroundColor:'blue',
  },

});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update: This question and my answer was based on class components. But functional components and hooks are the current way of using React for a long time now.

First you should create a state for your backgroundColor:

```js
const [backgroundColor, setBackgroundColor] = useState('blue');
```

then change it's value in your function

```js
setBackgroundColor('yellow');
```

and finally, use it in style prop:

```
style={[styles.style1, {backgroundColor}}
```

---

*Old answer, using class components*

You can give an array to style prop. So you can put any other styles from another sources.

First you should declare a default value for your backgroundColor state:

```js
this.state = {
  backgroundColor: 'blue',
};
```

then set it's state in your function as normal string state:

```js
this.setState({backgroundColor: 'yellow'});
```

and finally, use it in style prop:

```
style={[styles.style1, {backgroundColor: this.state.backgroundColor}]}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error Invariant Violation: Text strings must be rendered within a Text component. 

I tried to delete <View style={[styles.style1, this.state.style1]}> </View> and replaced it with :
<Text> {this.state.backgroundColor} </Text> 

      <View>
        <Button 
        onPress={this.change}> </Button>
       <Text> {this.state.backgroundColor} </Text> 
      </View>

Just to see if it changes the state, and it does.

 But why do I get that error?

Comment: Sorry for late answer :D That error means you have used text in a View component etc, or a syntax error. Most likely you accidently pressed a key accidently. i have just copy-pasted my answer and tested. It worked perfectly