# How to change the style of a View, by pressing a nested Button?

Tags: react-native, expo

I am learning React Native expo, and am trying to change the style (like background color) of a View, by pressing a Button inside it. This is what I have so far:

```
import { Button, View } from 'react-native';

var styles = {
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'blue'
  }
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button title='button' onPress={() => styles.A.backgroundColor = 'yellow'} />
    </View>

  );
}
```

But when I press the Button, I get the error `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'styles.A.backgroundColor = 'yellow'')` .
What am I missing? How do I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native set style as State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59795661/react-native-set-style-as-state)

Comment: @UgurEren I am somewhat new to React Native. The link you provide contains stuff I don't understand yet. Like constructor keyword or super function.

Comment: I feel like the answer should be much simpler.

Comment: The question uses a different kind of components (class components), You should only focus on the answer. You need to create a state using the [useState hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) and use that state's value in your View's style. You can then change the state's value in your Button's onPress function. Just like in the answer. If you're not familiar with the hooks concept, i suggest you should follow a guide or tutorial until you got the basics, it will prevent many headaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help and guidance from Uger Eren's comments, I was able to figure it out.

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, View } from 'react-native';

var styles = {
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  }
};

export default function App() {
  var [backgroundColor, setBackgroundColor] = useState('blue')
  return (
    <View style={[styles.container, {backgroundColor}]}>
      <Button title='button' onPress={() => setBackgroundColor('yellow')} />
    </View>

  );
}
```

It works!